# Error Correction in Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix for which I am supposed to find the solutions to Ax=0, however Linear Algebra was some time ago and I cannot remember how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

$A = \left[\matrix{ 1 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 0\\
                           0& 1 &1 &1 &0 &1\\
                           1& 1 &1 &0 &0 &0\\}\right]$

Comment: Hint: try the three rows of $A$ as possible solutions, remembering that you are working in GF$(2)$ or $\mathbb F_2$ and not the real (or complex field) that you were taught in the Linear Algebra course whose contents you have forgotten.

Comment: Over any field row reduction will be helpful, since it won't change the kernel (solutions to Ax=0).  Once you row reduce you'll know the dimension of the kernel and be able to pick out a basis for the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Row reduce your matrix, which doesn't affect the kernel.  I'll assume you are working over $\mathbb{F}_2$:

$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \end{array} \right]$ $\sim$ $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1  \end{array} \right]$

So the matrix has rank 3, and the kernel will have dimension 3.

Now write out the equations (I'll use $a,b,c,d,e,f$ for vars, with $d,e,f$ free):

$a=d+f \\ b=d+e \\ c=e+f \\ d=d \\ e=e \\f=f$

So you end up with kernel described by:

$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
e \\
f \end{array} \right]$ = 
$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \end{array} \right] d + $ $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0  \end{array} \right] e + $ $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\\end{array} \right] f$.

The three column vectors in front of $d,e,f$ on the RHS above are a basis for the kernel.  The same procedure works over any field.